# R-like object deletion and memory freeing in python?

Tags: python, r, memory

I'm coming from R, and I can't seem to figure out this super-basic problem in python.

Say I fit a random forest in R.  It's in an object called `rf`.  It takes up memory.  If I do `rm(rf)`, the memory is freed when I go look at `htop` or type `free` in the shell.

If I'm in python and fit a `RandomForestRegressor` and call it `rf`, then do `del rf`, *nothing happens*.

I can `import gc` and then `gc.collect()`, and *nothing happens*

Clearly python is too cool for something like this to be easy.  How do I get my memory back?

Comment: Do you have any lingering references to the object?

Comment: Python uses automatic garbage collection. CPython in particular uses reference counting. You likely still have a reference to your model somewhere.

Comment: The library you're using could theoretically be holding a reference too for God-knows-what reason.

Comment: you could also try `rf = None` although it would not remove the object from scope and could imply later use of the object

Comment: @badger0053 why would that be different than `del rf`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga setting rf to None is re-assigning the variable rather than signaling the `__del__` finalizer. references to rf will still exist except it will be a None object rather than a RandomForestRegressor. The downside is that it may cause developer confusion whereas `del rf` is clear on its intention

Comment: @badger0053 no, that isn't happening at all. `del rf` does not call `rf.__del__` (directly anyway). `del rf` simply *deletes the name `rf`*. The object that was being referenced by `rf` has one less reference. The same effect as `x = None`, and it is definitely not true that ". references to rf will still exist except it will be a None object rather than a RandomForestRegressor. ". All other references to the object are not affected by either `rf = None` or `del rf`.

Comment: I think the problem is that Python was not designed to be used for exploritory data analysis in a Jupyter notebook or an IPython shell. Both of these things create a lot of references to objects that you wouldn't even think (the REPL history, for example), which can cause your objects to linger. Note, just doing `my_obj` to see something  in a notebook or repl will create a reference to `my_object`, which will keep it alive

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for explaining. So if I'm understanding correctly, there is no difference in terms of garbage collection, but a difference if we want the name to exist?

Comment: @badger0053 yes, pretty much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you have another reference to it somewhere.

You can use `print(sorted(globals()))` and `print(sorted(locals()))` to list your current references if you need to debug this. If you're familiar with `gc`, you can use `gc.get_objects()` to see every referenced object. Use `del` to delete the references you don't need. When you have no reference to an object `Cpython` will automatically garbage collect.

That is the theory at least... Because, the module you're using can keep a reference too, and since you're keeping a reference to the module, it won't be garbage collected. You can delete references that the module holds (by using [introspection](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/object_introspection.html#dir)) or `del module` completely. Maybe your object has a `close` function or other that must be executed to free up resources (maybe it is [auto-closable](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)).

Needless to say that reference keeping is something a module should avoid.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like python creates lots of objects that I never told it to, as side effects.  Man, I wish people appreciated R more.  Such a better language for interactive work with data.